# Error Login Rails 3 "NameError in SessionsController#create "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to make a sample login with has_secure_password. The gem file is added, but this error persists:

```
undefined local variable or method `password_digest' for #<User:0x23129a0>
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:8:in `create'
```

In this file

```
sessions_controller.rb
```

line 8 looks like this:

```
if user and user.authenticate(params[:password])
```

---

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new

  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_name(params[:name])
    if user and user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to admin_url , notice: "Login efetuado com sucesso."
     else
       flash[:notice] = 'Usuario ou senha errados'
       redirect_to login_url
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to login_url, notice: "Logout Efetuado com sucesso."
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi there. Just to cover the bases, have you 1) added `has_secure_password` to your user model (in the user.rb file), and 2) added the `password_digest` attributed to your user model (via a migration)?

Comment: this is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759025/cant-use-has-secure-password-password-digest-error

Comment: How i add "attributed to your user model " ? my model user is: `class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true , uniqueness: true
  has_secure_password
end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Béla that this is a duplicate. However, here are step-by-step instructions in case the original answer wasn't clear enough.

To add the `password_digest` to your user model...

In the console do:

```
$ rails generate migration AddPasswordDigestToUsers
```

This will create a file something like: `/db/migrate/20120419234606_add_password_digest_to_users` (The fourteen digits at the beginning of your file will be different than mine since it's basically a time stamp for when you ran the generate command. You can read more on generating stand alone migrations [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration/%22here%22).)

Open the migration file you just created and edit so it looks something like this:

```
class AddPasswordDigestToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :password_digest, :string
  end
end
```

Save and close the file. Then, in the console, run:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
$ bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
```

At this point, your user model should have the `password_digest` attribute and (hopefully) you won't get the error any more.

Comment: Thanks for all i solve the problem before , the solution is make this colunm password_digest and make a new user , run fine.Thanks for the all.