# has_secure_password: undefined local variable or method 'password_digest' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bcrypt

As per title, when I try to call the following snippet on my user object:

`user = User.find_by(Username: username).try(:authenticate, password)`

I get the error:

`NameError (undefined local variable or method 'password_digest' for #...)`

**Steps I've taken**

My research led me to this question: [cant use has_secure_password, password_digest error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759025/cant-use-has-secure-password-password-digest-error)

- I can confirm that in my database I have a field named `PasswordDigest` which of course would match Ruby's `password_digest`
- I've also included `gem 'bcrypt'` in my gemfile and run `bundle install`
- I've also updated my test harness for the User model (I saw that mentioned somewhere online as a fix)

What other options can I explore in order to get this working?

Comment: your field in the database should be named : `password_digest` (with underscores and no upcase) !

Comment: Holy moly! Are you kidding me? I just assumed naturally that it was Ruby's naming convention corresponding to camel case!

Comment: It was that easy :-)

Comment: your database should only have underscore names. `Username` or `PasswordDigest` is not the convention and ugly as well :)

Comment: Thanks for that. And @TheCha͢mp I agree but I'm working with existing databases made by .NET devs!

Comment: ye then that makes the thing a bit trickier I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick workaround to your problem (if you cannot change `PasswordDigest` to `password_digest` in your DB) would be to create facade methods for this attribute.

If you look at the [has_secure_password source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7f18ea14c893cb5c9f04d4fda9661126758332b5/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb#L114) you can see where `password_digest` is used.

So your facade attributes would look something like this :

```
def password_digest=(astring)
  self['PasswordDigest']= astring
end

def password_digest
  self['PasswordDigest']
end
```

Not sure this is enough to cover all of it but it's a start.

Otherwise **change your DB fieldnames !!**

Comment: Excellent. After the commenters helped, I was really hoping for a tip like this. Thanks for teaching me something new :) I'm AFK right now but when I get back I think I'll re-work my question so I can mark this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In `authenticate` method, make the comparison of datebase `PasswordDigest` field like that to verify the password:

```
passwordDigest == Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(password)
```

**Key Point:** is the `Digest::SHA1.hexdigest`, it will convert your normal string to `hex` string which store in the database.

```
require 'digest/sha1'
Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("hello world")
=> "2aae6c35c94fcfb415dbe95f408b9ce91ee846ed"
```